# Sending multiple attachments in automated email using excel

Tags: excel, vba, email, macros, attachment

I am hoping that someone can help.

I have a macro in excel that looks down a column of email address and sends an individual email to those addresses with a specified attachment.
The macro works perfectly, however I am unsure how to adapt the macro to be able to send two attachments in the same email.

Please help.
The full code is;

```
Sub Send()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = Sheets("Email")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
    Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
            .HTMLBody = "<html><body><p>Hello " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & "<p></p>" _
            & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value & "</p><p>" _
            & cell.Offset(0, 3).Value _
            & Signature & "</body></html>"

            For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                    If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next FileCell

            .Send
            '.Display
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

Set OutApp = Nothing
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Not to do with your attachment issue, but be aware on your `.HTMLBody`  line your HTML syntax is not right, swap `<p></p>` with `</p><p>`

Answer (score 2):

You can run the

```
.Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
```

line twice with a different attachment path